# C# panel move with collision

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, collision

I am new to C# and Winforms and try to make a moving panel. It should move right until the end of my window and then back left. It should bounce from side to side. But the only thing happened after hours of trying is that it moves left and stops.

Using this form tools:

```
Timer = tmrMoveBox (interval: 50)
Panel = pnlBox
Label = lblXY (for showing the X and Y coordinates in the form)
```

Here are my first best try:

```
private void tmrMoveBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pnlBox.Location.X <= 316)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 316; i++)
        {
            pnlBox.Location = new Point(
                pnlBox.Location.X + 2, pnlBox.Location.Y);
            string BoxLocationToString = pnlBox.Location.ToString();
            lblXY.Text = BoxLocationToString;
        }
    }

    else if (pnlBox.Location.X >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i >= 316; i++)
        {
            pnlBox.Location = new Point(
                pnlBox.Location.X - 2, pnlBox.Location.Y);
            string BoxLocationToString = pnlBox.Location.ToString();
            lblXY.Text = BoxLocationToString;
        }
    }
}
```

And the second best try:

```
private void tmrMoveBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int runBox = 1;

    if(runBox == 1)
    {
        while (pnlBox.Location.X <= 316)
        {
            pnlBox.Location = new Point(
                pnlBox.Location.X + 2, pnlBox.Location.Y);
            string BoxLocationString = pnlBox.Location.ToString();
            lblXY.Text = BoxLocationString;
            runBox = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(pnlBox.Location.X > 0)
        {
            pnlBox.Location = new Point(
            pnlBox.Location.X - 2, pnlBox.Location.Y);
            string BoxLocationString = pnlBox.Location.ToString();
            lblXY.Text = BoxLocationString;
            runBox = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to use a while loop too but then the panel just disappears.
I'm no expert and just set this moving panel as a goal for myself. Hope anyone can give me a tip.

EDIT:

Form1.Designer.cs

```
 this.timer1.Interval = 50;
 this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tmrMoveBox);
 this.timer1.Start();
 this.timer1.Step = 2;
```

Comment: Do you have any timer? Where do you call this method?

Comment: Sorry I missed to add the timer line. I just drag and dropped the label, timer and panel out of the toolbox in the form of visual studio. Then I double-clicked it to edit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're using:

1. Windows Forms
2. WPF

Create a `Timer` and subscribe to the `Tick` event. Also, you should create new `int` property `Step`.

**1. Windows Forms:**

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
int Step;

Form1 () 
{
     InitializeComponent()
    ....
     t.Interval = 15000; // specify interval time as you want
     t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
     t.Start();

     this.Step = 2; 
}
```

And in ticks event handler put your logic, without while

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (pnlBox.Location.X >= 316)
        {
            Step = -2;
        }
        if (pnlBox.Location.X <= 0) 
        {
            Step = 2;
        }

        pnlBox.Location = new Point(
        pnlBox.Location.X + Step , pnlBox.Location.Y);
        string BoxLocationString = pnlBox.Location.ToString();
        lblXY.Text = BoxLocationString;
}
```

So your box will move on one step per one timer tick.

**1. WPF:**

As `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is not available, you may use  `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
t.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15); // hours, minutes, seconds (there are more constructors)
t.Tick += Timer_Tick;
t.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. But I have a question about the timer. Do I need to add the "_Tick" behind the name?

Comment: @user3772108 Its not necessary. You can select any other name you want.

Comment: @user3772108 Step is your class's property, not Timer's. I'll update answer

Comment: It seems like the program does not know step? 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer does not contain a definition for Step an now extension method Step..'.  I tried to use your first part of the code in the Form1.Designer.cs (Edit section in my post) and the second part in the Form1.cs.

Comment: @user3772108 Step is not part of the Timer, Step is your property.

Comment: Unbelievable it's working now! The important part I did wrong at last was to add the 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer...' under the namespace 'using' and not into the 'public partial class Form1 : Form1'.Thank you for your time and help this is great. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used:

```
int d= 10;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Reverse the direction of move after a collision
    if(panel1.Left==0 || panel1.Right==this.ClientRectangle.Width)
        d = -d;

    //Move panel, also prevent it from going beyond the borders event a point.
    if(d>0)
        panel1.Left = Math.Min(panel1.Left + d, this.ClientRectangle.Width - panel1.Width);
    else
        panel1.Left = Math.Max(panel1.Left + d, 0);
}
```

**Note:**

To check the collision you should check:

- Collision with left: `panel1.Left==0`
- Collision with right: `panel1.Right==this.ClientRectangle.Width`

You should not allow the panel goes beyond the borders even a point, so:

- The maximum allowed value for your panel left is `this.ClientRectangle.Width - panel1.Width`
- The minimum allowed value for your panel left is `0`

Also It's better to use `this.ClientRectangle.Width` instead of using hard coded 316.

Comment: The difference with the other answer is: My answer prevents the panel from going beyond the forms border even a bit, while in the other answer it first moves the panel and then in the next tick checks if the panel left is beyond the borders, reverses the movement. And you will see a panel that goes beyond the borders. Also another difference is in using in using this.ClientRectangle.Width instead of hard coding the width.

Comment: I try to understand the code. The reverse part is really cool but I don't get it what to do with the 'movement'. Is this an int? I tried 'panel1.Location.X' instead but it didn't work.

Comment: Now it's moving! I overlooked important of the d value for the second part completely. Thanks for this great solution and explanation. :)

Comment: You are welcome:) You should know you can only accept one answer by click on check mark near the answers. But you can vote for as many answer as you find useful, including the accepted one by click on up arrow near the answers, You can also vote for good questions. This makes Q/A more useful for future readers :)

Comment: `d = -d;` should be `d *= -d;` like before. other ways the movement speed to the left is slower then the movement to the right.

Comment: No, I previously used `d*=-1;` and now I use `d=-d`, both are equal. `d *= -d` is incorrect because it cause exponential increase.

Comment: You are right. I meant `-1` as you wrote before. :)
But the `d=-d` means `d = 10 - 10`?

Comment: No, d=-d means only changing the sign of d, but d-=d means d=10-10 means d=0

Comment: OK, sorry to say. I tested it again with `d = -1;` and this happens: Box move fast to the right -> Box moves slower to the left -> Box stops. But the other `d *= -1` works great so I just use this. Problem solved ;)

Comment: No problem, d=-1 is incorrect, and d=-d or d*=-1 are identical and correct :)